# Including a custom post type in the Archives widget

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets

I have a custom post type called "videos" that I want to include in the Archives widget (stock widget in the TwentyTwelve theme). It DOES already appear on the archives page, but just not in the widget.

I already have

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_main_query() )
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'videos' ) );
return $query;
}
```

in functions.php - can I modify the IF statement to be something like "if main query OR archive widget query"? How can I do this?

Comment: what is the status of this question, is it still unsolved?

Comment: Unfortunately still unsolved, see my reply to your answer below. However, I have decided to use a plugin for this, so I don't really need a solution anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The *Archive* widget is using `wp_get_archives()` to display the archive.

If you want to target all the `wp_get_archives()` functions, you can use the  `getarchives_where` filter to add your custom post type:

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_getarchives_where' );
function custom_getarchives_where( $where ){
    $where = str_replace( "post_type = 'post'", "post_type IN ( 'post', 'videos' )", $where );
    return $where;
}
```

If you want to target only the first *Archive* widget, you can try

```
add_action( 'widget_archives_args', 'custom_widget_archives_args' );
function custom_widget_archives_args( $args ){
    add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_getarchives_where' );
    return $args;
}
```

with

```
function custom_getarchives_where( $where ){
    remove_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'custom_getarchives_where' );
    $where = str_replace( "post_type = 'post'", "post_type in ( 'post', 'videos' )", $where );
    return $where;
}
```

where the filter is removed, to prevent affecting other parts.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The first issue is that it shows randomly inflated post counts for each month - for example, one month went from 5 to 29. The second issue is that the links don't include the ?post_type=videos part of the URL, so they don't work.

However, I have found a plugin called "Custom Post Type Archive" that does provide a widget that works. So I have decided to use that instead of coding it into the theme.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ok good to hear you found a solution. One would have to use the  `pre_get_posts` filter to add extra post types to the archive templates display, but appart from that I only tested it on the default theme TwentyTwelve where it worked ok in my case.

Comment: @birgire your code have a problem, that is why the post count is way off. `return $clauses;` should be `return $where;`. I've made the appropriate edit to your code :-)

Comment: doh! thanks @PieterGoosen  for correcting these silly typos ;-)

Comment: Pleasure. Answered a really big question about archive page and archive widgets, used your code for the widget (with credit), and the user came back with the same issue with the post count. :-), so fixed my answer and yours. Lol

Comment: hehe, great you solved it and saved the day ;-)

Comment: This proves the good value of code sharing and joint code reviews on this site ;-) Keep up the good work of bug hunting.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me:

```
class CPT_Archives extends WP_Widget
{
    function widget()
    {
        ...

        add_filter('getarchives_where', array($this, 'getarchives_where_filter'), 10, 2);

        $args = array(
            'format' => 'option',
            'echo'   => false,
        );
        $options = wp_get_archives($args);
        $options = str_replace('?m=', '?post_type=CPT&m=', $options);

        echo '<select name="CPT_archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">';
        echo '  <option value="">' . esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ) . '</option>';
        echo $options;
        echo '</select>';

        ...

    }

    function getarchives_where_filter($where)
    {
        $where = str_replace( "post_type = 'post'", "post_type = 'CPT'", $where );
        return $where;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you've done rather than simply posting code.